Unable add custom scope for MSAL entra Angular integration, When adding still using graph API
I am trying to integrate MSAL with Angular. I can able to generate access token with the help of Graph API. But token with nonce claim unable parse in the spring boot API. Therefore, I decided to use custom scope by creating an api in the Azure portal, but still MSAL is using the graph API. Added suggested implementation from MSAL and Azure.
Can anyone suggest how to apply custom scope without Graph API or Another approach?

Question isn't clear. Please include components involved. Use their names. Outline what exactly you're trying to achieve and where it is going wrong. Errors etc. Include code samples. A nonce has nothing to do with Graph. Which API is being called, is it by application, API->API, user->API etc.

To call the custom API, you need to expose an API in the Microsoft Entra ID application:

Grant admin consent to the API permission:

You need to pass this scope in the code like below:
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  scopeUri: ["api://API_CLIENTID/ScopeName"],
  tenantId: "TenantID",
  uiClienId: "ClientID",
  redirectUrl: "RedirectURL",
};

If still MSAL is using the Graph API, then exclude the scope of Microsoft Graph and pass scope as api://xxx/scopeName and modify your code.

Make sure access token aud is api://xxx or ClientID

Or refer the code below code snippet:
const config: Configuration = {
    auth: {
      clientId: <client id - your app's client id>,
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>`,
      redirectUri: RedirectURL,
    },
  };

  const params: AuthenticationParameters = {
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${Tenantid}`,
    scopes: [`${AppIDUri}/ScopeName`],  <-- the API that you're trying to call
  };

  const myMSAL = new UserAgentApplication(config);

Otherwise, you need to update the protectedResourceMap configuration option in your app.module.ts file to include the endpoint of your Spring Boot API:
{ protectedResourceMap: [ ['TheAPIEndpointHere', ['api://xxx/ScopeName']], ], })

References:
Azure AD Authentication through MSAL to connect Angular App to Asp.net Core web API (prishusoft.com)
Angular application using MSAL Angular to authenticate users with Azure AD for Customers and call a protected web API - Code Samples | Microsoft
